# I'm looking for a way to detect the ribbon load event

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, custom-actions

I'm looking for a way to hide a button from the ribbon using javascript, but to do this I need to wait until the elements of the ribbon are loaded.

Is there a way to detect such event?

Comment: Any reason why you can not use a HideCustomAction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx

Comment: Because I want to hide the Action under some conditions

Comment: Must19, i have similar issue of DOM being not available. How were you able to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some js that should load efter the ribbon is loaded:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
         // Your code here
      },
      "sp.ribbon.js");
```

More about modifying in [this blogpost](http://sharepointtaproom.com/2011/09/09/manipulating-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-with-javascript-part-1/)

Edit:

```
// Fires ‘ribbontabselected’ after the ribbon has been initialized after load
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
var pm = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
pm.add_ribbonInited(function () {
 // Your code here
});
}, ‘sp.ribbon.js’);
```

from [here](http://www.thetugboatcomplex.com/?p=883)

Comment: Thanx for the response. I tried this before, but do not garantee that the elements are attached to the dom.

Comment: Well I am not aware of any other events like "ribbon is loaded", so maybee you have to add a small delay in your code just to make sure all is loaded and well

Comment: Updated with a more "complex" sample

Comment: This worked fine. Thanx for helping